# Using Eval with var keywords in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, eval

Code in the backend:

```
var count = msgInfo.Count().ToString();
```

What I tried in the front-end:

```
<span><%#Eval("count")%></span>
```

However, my value is not displaying on the front-end. Does anyone know how can I do that with C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably will need to make count a field or property of the CodeBehind class

```
public string count;
```

Not a local variable in a method but a field/property on the CodeBehind class

Then you can set it's value anywhere else.

```
count  = msgInfo.Count().ToString();
```

You'll be able to access it in your markup

```
<span><%= count %> </span>
```

`Eval` is typically used to evaluate databinding expressions

Answer (score 3):

Declare count as a property of your page class:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string count {get; set;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```